# Getting OutofMemory issue when building with Android Studio 3.4 using code shrinker R8

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-r8

I'm using the latest stable version of Android Studio - 3.4. When I build a debug apk(without proguard) it works fine. But the issue comes when getting a release build. It uses the latest R8 shrinker by default.

It gives me an out of memory error. I tried changing the values in gradle.properties file like below, This occurs when executing the **transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease** task.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=2g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

and it still gives me the same error.

Finally I tried to disable the R8 by using this line in gradle.properties file,

```
android.enableR8=false
```

But still in build tasks I can see it is executing this task **transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease** and gives me the same error.

These are the error logs

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':appName:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:119)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.execute(ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:94)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:56)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:67)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.IdentityHashMap.init(IdentityHashMap.java:254)
at java.util.IdentityHashMap.<init>(IdentityHashMap.java:210)
at com.android.tools.r8.com.google.common.collect.Maps.newIdentityHashMap(Maps.java:511)
at com.android.tools.r8.com.google.common.collect.Sets.newIdentityHashSet(Sets.java:466)
at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.Enqueuer.transitionMethodsForInstantiatedClass(Enqueuer.java:1035)
at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.Enqueuer.processNewlyInstantiatedClass(Enqueuer.java:1014)
at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.Enqueuer.trace(Enqueuer.java:1467)
at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.Enqueuer.traceApplication(Enqueuer.java:1450)
at com.android.tools.r8.R8.run(R8.java:322)
at com.android.tools.r8.R8.run(R8.java:251)
at com.android.tools.r8.R8.lambda$runForTesting$1(R8.java:242)
at com.android.tools.r8.R8$$Lambda$463/1713263303.run(Unknown Source)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:62)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withR8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:50)
at com.android.tools.r8.R8.runForTesting(R8.java:238)
at com.android.tools.r8.R8.run(R8.java:148)
at com.android.builder.dexing.R8Tool.runR8(r8Tool.kt:189)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.R8Transform.transform(R8Transform.kt:260)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:47)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:284)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
```

So has anyone experienced this issue before? Has anyone figured out a solution?
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you solved?

Comment: @chathura : Did you solve it? Running into the same issue...

Comment: @RikvanVelzen Good news is you can update to android studio 3.5 and this issue has now been fixed.

Answer (score 9):

The error message:

> Caused by: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`: Java heap space

Refers to configuration `-Xmx`, where 4GB might not be enough.

Try giving more heap memory to; eg. `-Xmx5120M` or `-Xmx6144M`.

Comment: Tried with different values. even 8g,10g.

Comment: This advice applies to the `gradle.properties` file. If it doesn't already exist, the full line to add is `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m`, or whatever value you want to use

Comment: I also faced the same error in my React Native project and adding following line in my `gradle.properties` solved the issue for me.

`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Answer (score -2):

If this error appears suddenly. You should try the "Clean project". It will work

Build → Clean Project

[image]