# Minify WithR8 throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: android, kotlin, jvm, heap-memory

I'm facing a problem when trying to compile my app from command line using following command:

`./Project/gradlew -b ./Project/sampleapp/build.gradle assembleProd -x lint --stacktrace`

But command throws follwing error:

```
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
        at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_2.2.71.java:0)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.a0.a(SourceFile:89)
        at com.android.tools.r8.R8.a(R8.java:34)
        at com.android.tools.r8.R8.run(R8.java:3)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.R8Tool.runR8(r8Tool.kt:259)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$Companion.shrink(R8Task.kt:480)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task.doTaskAction(R8Task.kt:341)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(BaseTask.kt:63)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask.taskAction(NonIncrementalTask.kt:90)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
        ... 94 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I've tried many solutions that I found in stackoverflow, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55891365/getting-outofmemory-issue-when-building-with-android-studio-3-4-using-code-shrin) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56420132/obfuscating-app-with-r8-causes-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded), but none of them has worked.

1. Changed gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms4096m -Xmx8192m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

2. Changed gradlew file to add JAVA_OPTS and GRADLE_OPTS:

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Xms4096m -Xmx8192m"
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4096m -Xmx8192m"
GRADLE_OPTS="-Xms4096m -Xmx8192m"
```

3. Changed zshrc:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4096m -Xmx8192m"
export GRADLE_OPTS="-Xms4096m -Xmx8192m"
```

4. Added dexOptions javaMaxHeapSize to build.gradle:

```
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
    }
```

Nothing worked :(
I'm using a MacOs 11.6.2 with 16GB RAM

I don't know what to try anymore.

Answer (score 8):

The problem was solved puting the `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms4096m -Xmx8192m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` configuration in the global `gradle.properties` file, found in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` and not only in the project properties.